# Need the equivalent of a "paired T-test" for percentages (test-retest comparison between groups)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, paired-data, group-differences

I have an observational study with a control group and a treatment group (n=25). All the subjects are given the same test (which consists of 9 questions,  each of which has 4 multiple choice answers). Then the treatment group is given training and the control group isn't. The same test is given to all the subjects again (post treatment). I want to compare the differences in the scores (post - pre) between the 2 groups to see if, on average, the treatment group improved more, if the improvement was statistically significant (hypothesis test), and estimate the magnitude of the improvement (lconfidence interval). I need the equivalent of a paired test but for percentages.

I don't think I can directly run a paired T-test because of my small sample size, not to mention the fact that the distribution for the number of correct responses (which seems to be small for some questions) is probably going to violate the normality condition.

EDIT: It has been pointed out that there is an approach called "difference in difference" that does seem to be what I am trying to do, but I am finding little work on how to do inference with it (i.e. hypothesis testing and confidence intervals). But I don't work in the fields that use this methodology, so maybe someone can point me to a reference that gives these results.

Comment: how is the pre test and post test score aggregated from the individual questions?

Comment: Search this site for 'difference in difference' and see if that matches what you have.

Comment: @BruceET Yes I believe this is what I am looking for. I had never heard this term before, so thank you for pointing that out. I need to look into it and think about it some more.

Comment: @BruceET  The problem I am finding with this "difference in difference" approach is doing inference with it. I can't seem to find any results about how to do hypothesis testing or confidence intervals with it. Is this a limitation of this approach?

Comment: If you want to do it per question then McNemar's test may be what you need, assuming each question is just scored correct/incorrect.

Comment: @mdewey Yes McNemars test would be the best tool for single question analysis within one group. BUT, it would not let me compare groups, nor would it let me test and estimate the effects due to the group (which is kind of the main thrust of the project). I know I could do logistic regression, but again, I'm going to be looking at odds ratios (which will give me evidence of an association, along with its direction, significance and estimate) but will not tell me about the difference in the performance.

Comment: In McNemar's test the ones who remain the same are uninformative so you can ignore them. That reduces it to two values in each group the ones who went correct-incorrect and the ones who went incorrect-correct. Now compare them between your two treatments with odds ratio or risk ratio.